# how to install the latest flash on RHEL 5.3 to support Chromium browser?

Tags: installation, chromium, redhat-enterprise-linux, flash-player

I've installed chromium on Linux from a custom binary on the net. When I try to get to gmail or any other site that uses flash, chromium warns me that the version of flash that is shipped with the browser is stale and that I should be using the latest version and pointing to an adobe site.

the adobe site gives me 3 options
1) yum
2) RPM
3) tar.gz
4) APT for ubuntu

since I'm on redhat, I can use either yum or RPM.

Which one should I use and what is the command to install it so that chromium can use it.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Fedora is the upstream of both RHEL & Centos, I guess you can follow the instructions bellow:
http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Flash

Comment: that worked just fine for me on a 32-bit install.